# How to create n threads, each one creates n - 1 threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I am working with a large project and I am trying to create a test that does the following thing: first, create 5 threads. Each one of this threads will create 4 threads, which in turn each one creates 3 other threads. All this happens until 0 threads.
I have **_ThreadInit()** function used to create a thread:

`status = _ThreadInit(mainThreadName, ThreadPriorityDefault, &pThread, FALSE);`

where the 3rd parameter is the output(the thread created).

What am I trying to do is start from a number of threads that have to be created **n = 5**, the following way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   // here call the _ThreadInit method which creates a thread
}
```

I get stuck here. Please, someone help me understand how it should be done. Thanks^^

Comment: Create a function `MyCoolThread` which will take as a parameter the number of threads to create. This function will create that many threads, while passing itself as a thread function with a parameter one less. Pretty much as with recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Eugene Sh.'s comment, you could create a function that takes a parameter, which is the number of threads to create, that calls itself recursively.

Example using standard C threads:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

int MyCoolThread(void *arg) {
    int num = *((int*)arg);     // cast void* to int* and dereference

    printf("got %d\n", num);

    if(num > 0) {               // should we start any threads at all?
        thrd_t pool[num];
        int next_num = num - 1; // how many threads the started threads should start

        for(int t = 0; t < num; ++t) { // loop and create threads
            // Below, MyCoolThread creates a thread that executes MyCoolThread:

            if(thrd_create(&pool[t], MyCoolThread, &next_num) != thrd_success) {

                // We failed to create a thread, set `num` to the number of 
                // threads we actually created and break out.

                num = t;
                break;
            }
        }

        int result;

        for(int t = 0; t < num; ++t) {   // join all the started threads
            thrd_join(pool[t], &result);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int num = 5;
    MyCoolThread(&num); // fire it up
}
```

Statistics from running:

```
      1 thread  got 5
      5 threads got 4
     20 threads got 3
     60 threads got 2
    120 threads got 1
    120 threads got 0
```

Comment: This is helpful, the problem is I have to use some predefined functions. _ThreadInit is one of them. I can't use thrd_create or thrd_join, that is why I find it difficult to solve this

Comment: @Gloria I see. I don't know `_ThreadInit` from any of the threading libraries I've used - but the algorithm should be reuseable with any threading library. Create the first thread with n=5 as argument, then loop and create n-1 thread using the same thread start function. After that's been done, join all the started threads.

Comment: @Gloria I got curious about `_ThreadInit` and wanted to find info about it. What's the name of the threading library? Do you have a link to any online documentation about this library?

Comment: No, not really. There's nothing public anyways

Comment: @Gloria Ok. Too bad that they don't teach you about the standard stuff first and about special libraries later :-( Did you have any success converting the ideas in the answer to the threading library you use? I'm _pretty_ sure that it will support what I put in the answer, one way or another.

Comment: Yes, I managed to do that. Thanks :)

Comment: @Gloria Oh, great! You're welcome!